# How to get the total sales of immediate subordinate based on sales of all subordinate in charge in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, recursive-query

the structure is as follows:

```
ID_EMPLOYEE   ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS     LEVEL
        -------------------------------------------
            100           NULL                1
            201           100                 2
            202           100                 2
            301           201                 3
            302           201                 3
            303           202                 3
            304           202                 3
            401           302                 4
            402           302                 4
            403           302                 4
            N             N-1                 N
```

And structure for sales

```
ID_EMPLOYEE           SALE        DATE
    401               1100.00     2015-06-07
    402               1500.00     2015-06-05
    403               1400.00     2015-06-25
    303               5000.00     2015-05-25
    304               8250.00     2015-05-25
```

I tried this

```
WITH Sales_CTE (ID_EMPLOYEE, SALE, MONTHS)
AS
(
    SELECT ID_EMPLOYEE, sum(SALE), DATEPART(mm,DATE)
    FROM SALES
    GROUP BY ID_EMPLOYEE, DATEPART(mm,DATE)
)
SELECT JE.ID_EMPLOYEE, OS.SALE, OS.MONTHS,
    JE.ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS, OM.SALE, OM.MONTHS
FROM EMPLOYEES AS JE
    JOIN Sales_CTE AS OS
    ON JE.ID_EMPLOYEE= OS.ID_EMPLOYEE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales_CTE AS OM
    ON JE.ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS= OM.ID_EMPLOYEE
    WHERE ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS= 302
ORDER BY JE.ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS;
```

Currently only I can see sales employee level n-1 immediate, but I want to show as follows. For example employee 100 can see

```
ID_EMPLOYEE  SALES    MONTH
201           4000    6
202          13250    5
```

This n levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prepare schema**

```
CREATE TABLE STRUCTURE(ID_EMPLOYEE INT, ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS INT, LEVEL INT)
CREATE TABLE SALES(ID_EMPLOYEE INT,SALE INT,DDATE  DATE)
```

**Prepare data**

```
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (100,NULL,1)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (201,100, 2)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (202,100, 2)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (301,201, 3)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (302,201, 3)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (303,202, 3)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (304,202, 3)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (401,302, 4)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (402,302, 4)
INSERT INTO STRUCTURE VALUES (403,302, 4)

INSERT INTO SALES VALUES(401,1100.00,'2015-06-07')
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES(402,1500.00,'2015-06-05')
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES(403,1400.00,'2015-06-25')
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES(303,5000.00,'2015-05-25')
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES(304,8250.00,'2015-05-25')
```

**Query**

```
WITH Sales_CTE
AS
(
SELECT ID_EMPLOYEE,ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS,ID_EMPLOYEE AS ROOTID 
FROM STRUCTURE 
WHERE ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS=100

UNION ALL

SELECT S.ID_EMPLOYEE,S.ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS,SC.ROOTID
FROM STRUCTURE S 
        INNER JOIN Sales_CTE SC ON SC.ID_EMPLOYEE = S.ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS
)

SELECT SC.ROOTID AS ID_EMPLOYEE,SUM(S.SALE) AS SALES,MONTH(S.DDATE) AS [MONTH]
FROM Sales_CTE SC 
       INNER JOIN SALES S ON S.ID_EMPLOYEE = SC.ID_EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY SC.ROOTID,MONTH(S.DDATE)
ORDER BY SC.ROOTID,MONTH(S.DDATE)
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b641d/1

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks friend is very helpful